# How to reset textarea with summernote

Tags: reset, summernote

In a form after submitting all fields get cleared other than the TEXTAREA.
I use summernote for textarea. (using bootstrap)

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(function(){
$('#description').summernote({height: 500});
});//]]>  
</script>
```

`#description` is the id of the textarea.

reset done like below

```
<script>
$('#submit-box')[0].reset();
</script>
```

`#submit-box` is the id of the form

Answer (score 10):

```
$('#description').code('');
```

see http://hackerwins.github.io/summernote/features.html#api-code

**Updated**

Since summernote v0.6.4+(maybe), the API has breaking changes.

```
$('#description').summernote('code', '');
```

http://summernote.org/getting-started/#get-amp-set-code

Answer (score 5):

another way :

```
$('#description').summernote('reset');
```

Comment: That is the documented method, but I can't get it to work, hence why I'm here.

Comment: Turns out I had an older version...whoops.