# How to clear Summernote WYSIWYG Editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, summernote

I like to know how to clear the Summernote. Here is a link to bootstrap Summernote

http://summernote.org

I try using

```
$('#MyForm').delay(1000).resetForm(1000);
```

And

```
$('#MyForm').trigger("reset");
```

Also i tried

```
$('#SummernoteTxt').val('');
```

1st two codes rest the whole form correctly but doesn't seems to clear the Summernote editor. Can anyone point me how to do this.

Comment: MAybe this similar question will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26425342/how-to-reset-textarea-with-summernote

Comment: Great it work. Thank you. Can you added as the answer so i can mark it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 18):

You can clear contents with `code`.

```
$('#summernote').summernote('code', '');
```

You can also clear all stored history, with `reset` after v0.7.3.

```
$('#summernote').summernote('reset');
```

Fore more details...
http://summernote.org/deep-dive/#reset

Answer (score 2):

As user2314737 pointed out on the link below code work

```
$('#MyForm').code('');
```

Answer (score 2):

Worked for me, only put below jquery code.

```
$('#ControlId').code('');
```

Here **ControlId** is the id of the summernote editor.

Comment: Worked for me also,

Answer (score 1):

### Reset

To Clear the editor content and remove all stored history.

```
$('#summernote').summernote('reset');
```